# Run .cmd file using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am new to PowerShell. I am writing a script which automatically updates patches of a product in the remote server by copying the required files from the shared location.

in the below snippet, the path is shown correctly, however, the install.cmd is not get executed.

Kindly let me know where am I making mistake.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $s -ScriptBlock {
    $s = $args[0]
    $chrome_archive_name = $args[1]
    $chrome_Install_Path = $args[2]  
    $command = "\\" + $s + "\" + $chrome_Install_Path + "\" + $chrome_archive_name +'\install.cmd'
    Start-Process -FilePath $command -Verb RunAs
    } -ArgumentList $s, $chrome_archive_name, $chrome_Install_Path
```

Comment: Did you make sure your $command is being called correctly? What happens when you do Write-host $command ?

Comment: this is the path stored in $command "\\ServerName\C$\Temp\Google\install.cmd"  . I am calling it using "Start-Process -FilePath $command -Verb RunAs"